# Include map overview details in a legend?

Tags: qgis, print-composer, legend, map-overviews, composer-manager

I'm creating a map to show BRUV sites in different marine zones.

There are 6 zones (created an overview for each - please see attached image). The zones are individually displayed in smaller map insets below the legend with site locations and BRUV status.

Is it possible to include the overview information for marine zone in the map legend, for example... I would like the legend to display **Zone** and **1-6** as map items.

[image: outcome]

The maps were created manually as I was unsure how to utilise atlas (that's another question but I will not go into that)

**UPDATE/EDIT!**

Ok, today I created what I desired by hand, manually drawing text boxes, choosing colour, measuring symbol space...  This was time consuming. I don't mind taking the time to do it, but, it's a pain in the bum when I need to repeat the process for another project + I would like to  experiment with colours, text or placement and so forth. It would be splendid if there was an automatic way.

[image: legend]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you could try is the following approach:

- Create a Shapelayer which represents the bounderies of the detailed maps
- Add a field which holds your additional Information like "Conservation"
- add a field  "zone" and another field "bounds" to the shapefile.
- in The field "zone" write yopur zoner number 1,2,3.., n
- In the field bounds go to fieldcalculator and write `bounds($geometry)` to get the bounding box --> **Does not work appearendly see edit**
- in the print composer set the extend of the detail maps to the values of the field "bounds"
- now you can activate the bounderies layer in the overview map and style it with labels and classifiy it with your info field

**EDIT:**

The bounds method does not seems to work:

- try to create 4 fields instead with `x_min($geometry)`, `x_max($geometry)`, `y_min($geometry)` and `y_max($geometry)` as inputs from the field calculator

Comment: Perfect, it was in the back of my mind somewhere but you have laid that out nicely. I will try this approach from now on. Thank you @LaughU

Comment: have a look at my edit as well. I didnt get a good result with bounds but the method with the 4 edges should work